# PostgreSQL unable to INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, pgadmin

I want to reflect info from one table into another one. Ideally, I would need to use a function (will be upgrading afterwards). I have a first table called tb_user, with data from users (simple user names such as `U0001, U0002`....).

I was doing the following:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_user_statshot    (
    user_code                       CHARACTER(5) NOT NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_calculatet() RETURNS void AS 
$$
DECLARE 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tb_user_statshot (user_code)
    SELECT user_code FROM tb_user;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

I expect the users code to reflect in my new `statshot` table, but this is no happening. Does anyone know why?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you remember to commit? If you did - are you getting any error?

Comment: I did commit, but I'm not getting errors... it's just not updating.

Comment: @robert_gonzalez have you really called "sp_calculatet" ? in your code , you are just defining the function

Comment: Is this a `search_path` problem where you have more then one `tb_user_statshot` and you are not looking at the correct one? Why not just use the query directly?